# Why does the Symbiote no longer set off Spider-Man's spider-sense?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, venom

One of the most dangerous aspects of Venom is that he doesn't set off Spider-Man's spider-sense. The explanation for this was always that it had once been his costume and being in proximity to him, his warnings did not register the symbiote as a threat.

But when Spidey first gets the symbiote, it does set off his spider-sense as seen here:

[image: Symbiote triggers the spider-sense]

> What the heck is ***that***--? And why is it making my spider-sense tingle?

So what happened?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would suspect that reason the symbiote doesn't set off Peter's spider-sense has something to do with their previous fusion. When he first discovered the symbiote, they weren't linked yet.

Comment: Certainly a point- I don't know if he ever refers to it afterwards or anything. If not, I will certainly accept a "it's never really discussed" as an answer.

Comment: I can't find an exact source to reference, but the explanation I recall is that the symbiote merged Peter's DNA into its own, so Peter's Spider-Sense doesn't register danger from "Peter".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Even Marvel doesn't quite seem to know.

[Marvel.com sort of handwaved the explanation in a previous version of their bio for Brock](https://web.archive.org/web/20160412030400/http://marvel.com/universe/Brock,_Eddie):

[image: Marvel's old bio for Brock]

> Brock taunted Peter Parker with minor assaults, such as pushing him in front of a moving subway train. **The alien costume could cancel out the wall-crawler’s spider-sense presumably by projecting conflicting frequencies upon Spider-Man's brain waves.**

The generally accepted answer you'll find discussed is that the symbiote takes on DNA or abilities of its hosts. Peter's Spider-Sense does not register non-threats, and the Symbiote exploits this by somehow (see the "presumably" even in the Marvel.com description) confusing Peter's senses by appearing to be a non-threat or even Peter himself.

Comment: The quote doesn't appear to come from Marvel.com, it appears to come from the fan-wiki; http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_Brock_(Earth-616)

Comment: It came from Marvel.com at the time of posting, as you can see in [the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160412030400/http://marvel.com/universe/Brock,_Eddie).

Comment: @phantom42 Can you edit that into your answer?

Comment: You might want to make it clearer in the answer that at this point the marvel.com site was a fan-written wiki, albeit one that had regular participation from the Marvel production team

Comment: As a note, I love the notion that Pete's spider sense detects the symbiote as _himself_.  "Hmm... something's being awfully noisy in that kitchen over there, but my spider sense says it's just me raiding the fridge.  ...I'll ignore it."

Answer (score 0):

Spider-sense doesn't affect clones of Peter Parker or people he trusts (not exactly scientific). Here's some semblance to an explanation but I think it's because it adds suspense to the story.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.cbr.com/spider-man-15-things-you-never-knew-about-his-spider-sense/amp/